# Is it advisable to reload Pro Mini with the bootloader originally designed for UNO to save 1.5 KB flash space?

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader, arduino-pro-mini

In order to allow **bigger user program size**, is it possible and advisable to **reload Pro Mini** with the boot loader originally **designed for UNO**. This will save 1.5 KB flash space (UNO boot loader is 0.5KB, Pro Mini is 2KB).

Using a smaller boot loader is an 'intermediate' step to get more space while still enjoy the easy benefit of the Arduino IDE and many library/code example. Of course, ultimate step is to remove all boot loader (only small saving of 0.5KB if above is possible) and switch to ATmel development environment, ATmel studio, which is complex but programmer has full control of everything.

Did I miss anything in the followings?

I tend to believe that it is possible as

a) same ATMega328 chip is used in both board

b) Pro Mini is essentially cutting UNO into two halves, the MCU and the USB/Serial converter now use external USB to Serial converter

If the Pro Mini board is reloaded with UNO boot loader, how should the boards.txt file be edited to reflect the changes so that the IDE will handle it correctly?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just pick up an ISP programmer and use that instead?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Question edited to clarify the intermediate (save 1.5KB) and ultimate (save 2KB but much more complex) steps.

Comment: No, the intermediate step is to use a programmer. `Tools` | `Programmer`, `File` | `Upload Using Programmer`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - No. That is the *final* step.  The *intermediate* step (and imho the one usually worth stopping at) is to use a small bootloader and **leverage the same serial interface connector for debug and loading**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Using ISP doesn't prevent `Serial` and the serial monitor from working. It simply allows you to control the fuse bytes and use all of the flash and EEPROM on the chip.

Comment: Of course it doesn't prevent it, but removing the bootloader and *relying* on ISP does prevent you from using the serial connection for program loading.  And it's explicitly not what the poster wants to do or is asking about for this stage of their project.

Comment: If you have an ISP setup, you are in a position to find out of the Uno or other small bootloader will work, **and to restore the original if it doesn't** (which would likely be only for some odd quirk, such as a mutual baud rate approximation)

Comment: Thanks responders for pointing out that Arduino IDE can do both boot loader and ISP modes. The later is new information for me and helpful in choosing best approach under different stages and situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just flash the newest [optiboot_atmega328-Mini.hex](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arduino/Arduino/master/hardware/arduino/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328-Mini.hex). That one should also be only .5k in size, as it starts writing at the same address (`7E00`).

If you divide `7E00` by two you get `3F00` (This is because AVRs use 16-bit words for addressing while .hex files work with bytes (8-bit)). (I figured that one out, just now)

`3F00` is exactly the start of the `Boot Loader Flash Section` when you  have selected a 256-words `Boot Size` (page 291 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)). 256-words is the 0.5kb you want.

Just make sure you have the `BOOTSZ1`, `BOOTSZ0` fuses set to `1`

As for the `boards.txt`. I think you only need to change `mini328.upload.maximum_size=28672` to `mini328.upload.maximum_size=32256`.